# how does toByte work while bit manipulation in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

The document for bit manipulation in python states

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation

as example, the following code

```
import ctypes
c_uint8 = ctypes.c_uint8

class Flags_bits( ctypes.LittleEndianStructure ):
    _fields_ = [
                ("logout",     c_uint8, 1 ),  # asByte & 1
                ("userswitch", c_uint8, 1 ),  # asByte & 2
                ("suspend",    c_uint8, 1 ),  # asByte & 4
                ("idle",       c_uint8, 1 ),  # asByte & 8
               ]

class Flags( ctypes.Union ):
    _anonymous_ = ("bit",)
    _fields_ = [
                ("bit",    Flags_bits ),
                ("asByte", c_uint8    )
               ]

flags = Flags()
flags.asByte = 0x2  # ->0010

print( "logout: %i"      % flags.bit.logout   )
# `bit` is defined as anonymous field, so its fields can also be accessed directly:
print( "logout: %i"      % flags.logout     )
print( "userswitch:  %i" % flags.userswitch )
print( "suspend   :  %i" % flags.suspend    )
print( "idle  : %i"      % flags.idle       )
```

so i figured out that setting the value to asByte is leading to the value being parsed into the c_uint8, but i am unable to understand the logic behind this. When we set the asByte value, does python work back from the asByte value set to update the value for individual components that make the class. Also as a side note, i was not able to find documentation for asByte. If someone can point me to it, it'd be great.

Comment: The very link you posted in your question links to the ctypes documentation, which has chapters for [Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) and [bit fields](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#bit-fields-in-structures-and-unions).

Comment: @Rawing, yes i am aware of documentation (i read it before posting) for Union and bit fields but neither actually cover how asByte can be used as it is being used in the example code.

Comment: What do you mean "used as it is being used"? The only usage I can see is an assignment to it. Of course you can assign values to fields, does the documentation really need to mention that? If you're wondering why an assignment to `asByte` changes the `logout` and `suspend` etc. attributes, that's because it's a Union - they occupy the same byte in your computer's memory.

Comment: yes, that is what i was asking, makes sense now